# List Template for FB using Bot framework node.js V4

Tags: node.js, botframework

Can anyone please help me to include list view in Facebook Channel using Bot framework? I saw examples as shown here [List template](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3169). I don't know whether this is the exact way in which we need to give the attachments. Also I didn't know the equivalent for sourceEvent method in Bot framework v4. Another useful link is as follows [FB Messenger Message Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429355/fb-messenger-message-template). See the image given below. I need to put the link for the image and once we click the link it should open another page also the image should be clickable image as in the example for **C#** [Clickable HeroCard images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283764/clickable-herocard-images) using **tap property**. Both functionality should work. I tried using **HeroCard** (but the url that needs to open-up had CORS origin issue.  I tried using **Adaptive card** but it is not supported in Facebook as of now. So, I thought to use List Template for Facebook. Is there anyway to achieve this?

[image: This is the actual requirement.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send Facebook List Templates through the Microsoft BotFramework by adding the Facebook attachment to the activity's channel data. The `list` template type doesn't seem to be supported, but you can set the type to `generic` and add multiple elements to the attachment to get the same result. See the example below.

```
await turnContext.sendActivity({
    channelData: {
        "attachment": {
            "type": "template",
            "payload": {
              "template_type": "generic",
              "elements": [
                {
                    "title": "Three Strategies for Finding Snow",
                    "subtitle": "How do you plan a ski trip to ensure the best conditions? You can think about a resort’s track record, or which have the best snow-making machines. Or you can gamble.",
                    "image_url": "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/02/10/travel/03update-snowfall2/03update-snowfall2-jumbo.jpg?quality=90&auto=webp",
                    "default_action": {
                      "type": "web_url",
                      "url": "https://www.nytimes.com/2019/02/08/travel/ski-resort-snow-conditions.html",
                      "messenger_extensions": false,
                      "webview_height_ratio": "tall"
                    },
                    "buttons": [{
                            "type":"element_share"
                    }]
                  },
                {
                    "title": "Viewing the Northern Lights: ‘It’s Almost Like Heavenly Visual Music’",
                    "subtitle": "Seeing the aurora borealis has become a must-do item for camera-toting tourists from Alaska to Greenland to Scandinavia. On a trip to northern Sweden, the sight proved elusive, if ultimately rewarding.",
                    "image_url": "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/02/17/travel/17Northern-Lights1/17Northern-Lights1-superJumbo.jpg?quality=90&auto=webp",
                    "default_action": {
                      "type": "web_url",
                      "url": "https://www.nytimes.com/2019/02/11/travel/northern-lights-tourism-in-sweden.html",
                      "messenger_extensions": false,
                      "webview_height_ratio": "tall"
                    },
                    "buttons": [{
                            "type":"element_share"
                    }]
              },
              {
                    "title": "Five Places to Visit in New Orleans",
                    "subtitle": "Big Freedia’s rap music is a part of the ether of modern New Orleans. So what better authentic travel guide to the city that so many tourists love to visit?",
                    "image_url": "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/02/17/travel/17NewOrleans-5Places6/17NewOrleans-5Places6-jumbo.jpg?quality=90&auto=webp",
                    "default_action": {
                      "type": "web_url",
                      "url": "https://www.nytimes.com/2019/02/12/travel/big-freedia-five-places-to-eat-and-visit-in-new-orleans.html",
                      "messenger_extensions": false,
                      "webview_height_ratio": "tall"
                    },
                    "buttons": [{
                            "type":"element_share"
                    }]
                }]
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it possible to make it as clickable image? I mean, if I click on the image it should open to a webpage?

Comment: I understood, how to include that by using the attribute "default_actions", Anyone can refer the following link to do it [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/list](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/list)

Comment: Not "default_actions" instead use "default_action"

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer with the `default_actions`

Comment: Here, when we apply the _default_actions_ , the link is visible automatically. Can we disable the link?